# Do I need mysql-client for PHP/Python etc interactions?

Tags: php, python, mysql, linux, webserver

I am setting up a production server for the first time and would like to make sure I only have what I need for security prepress.

By "interactions" since I'm also new to programming, I think I mean "API calls".

Do I need mysql-client on a Linux (Debian) server to be able to 'talk' to mysql with any programming language? As I think there isn't any point installing the client on the production server if I can remotely send commands from mysql-client on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect code running on the production server to connect to a mysql db, then yes.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure whether code talking to mysql went through mysql-server or mysql-client.

Comment: You're welcome. It feels like what you were considering "should" work, but would require a rather interesting configuration involving capturing and forwarding the request packet from the client instance to the application server and subsequently to the db server in a proxies connection that really isn't worth the trouble. :)